# Changing session timeout behaviour?

Tags: session, timeout

In force.com session timeout are handled by server sending a redirect and setting the location header to a page in force domain. This will cause a re-challenge and re-authentiation.

Is it possible to set what the location header is set to from the session timeout?

Or change the behaviour for session timeouts in any way?

Comment: Session settings decide the time out limit .I think only way is using the session settings  configuration